# How to have 2 different maps on the same page

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I'm new to both angular and leaflet. Trying to get 2 maps on the same page but when I add the second map i get the error:Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'bFC' is not a function, got undefined.  I've searched for a solution but came up short - most seam to deal with using two different sets of geoJSON files.  Any help is much appreciated, thanx!

Here is my code:

```
**index.html**
<div class="container">
<!-- BaseMap -->
<div ng-controller="bFC">
    <h1>First Step Basic Map</h1>
    <leaflet width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet> 
</div> 

<!-- CenterMap -->
<div ng-controller="centerMap">
    <h1>Center Map</h1>
    <leaflet lf-center="dc"width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="number" step="any" ng-model="dc.lat" />Latitude</li>
        <li><input type="number" step="any" ng-model="dc.lng" />Longitude</li>
        <li><input type="number" step="any" ng-model="dc.zoom" />Zoom</li>
    </ul>
</div>  


</div>

**baseMap.ctr.js**

(function() {

"use strict";

angular
    .module("demomap", ['leaflet-directive'])
    .controller("bFC", bFC);

function bFC($scope) {

}   

})();


**centerMap.ctr.js**

(function() {

"use strict";

angular
    .module("demomap", ['leaflet-directive'])
    .controller("centerMap", centerMap);

function centerMap($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        dc : {
            lat: 38.91,
            lng: -77.03,
            zoom: 4
        }
    });

}   

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new module if you do this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [...]);
```

If you want to get an exist module, you should remove the second argument like this:

```
angular.module('myModule');
```

The module "demomap" in the centerMap.ctr.js is duplicated. It will create a new module and replace the one in the baseMap.ctr.js. Just Remove the second argument of the module function in the centerMap.ctr.js.